# When does MQ throw the JMS Exception 'MQJMS1022: failed to redirect message'?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, mq

When does MQ throw the JMS Exception 'MQJMS1022: failed to redirect message' ?

Our application(running on JDK 1.5) is connected to MQ 7.5.
While reading the message from MQ the following exception is thrown.

```
 javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS1022: failed to redirect message
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.services.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:530)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver.receiveAsync(MQQueueReceiver.java:734)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.SessionAsyncHelper.run(SessionAsyncHelper.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
```

There is no stack trace from our application code.
Does anyone know what could be the reason.
The MQ documentation is very poor and i couldn't find much info about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a really good idea to also dump out the LinkedException.
i.e.

```
catch (JMSException e)
{
   System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
   System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The LinkedException will contain the MQ Reason Code.

Comment: I didn't have the source code. Decompiled the class and extracted the underlying exception. I fixed that issue and it worked. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Exception: MQJMS1022: failed to redirect message : 
can be caused if there is a poison message, and application 
attempts to back it out. If there is no backout queue defined on a 
queue manager, MQ has nowhere to put the message, hence the exception. 
Please confirm if you have defined the backout queue.   The [knowledge center page about handling poison messages](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm35205_.htm) may be helpful

Comment: We had a backout queue configured already. The issue was because of some exception that was not printed in logs. I some how managed to find the root cause and fixed this fixed. Thanks for a detailed information about this error code. I could not find such detail anywhere else.